# Drawing a PDF Right-Side-Up in CGContext

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm overriding the drawRect: method in a custom UIView, and I'm doing some custom drawing. All was going well, until I needed to draw a PDF resource (a vector glyph, to be precise) into the context. First I retrieve the PDF from a file:

```
NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CardKit.bundle/A.pdf"]];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDoc, 1);
```

Then I create a box with the same dimensions as the loaded PDF:

```
CGRect box = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFArtBox);
```

Then I save my graphics state, so that I don't screw anything up:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
```

And then I perform a scale+translate of the CTM, theoretically flipping the whole context:

```
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, rect.size.height);
```

I then scale the PDF so that it fits into the view properly:

```
CGContextScaleCTM(context, rect.size.width/box.size.width, rect.size.height/box.size.height);
```

And finally, I draw the PDF and restore the graphics state:

```
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pdfPage);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

The issue is that there is nothing visible drawn. All this code should theoretically draw the PDF glyph into the view, right?

If I remove the scale+translate used to flip the context, it draws perfectly:  it just draws upside-down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try doing the translate before the scale:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, rect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
```

Comment: This produces the exact same result, I'm afraid.

Comment: Carter Allen: The code as I have corrected it should work just fine. Translating and then scaling is exactly what you need to do to flip (or, in this case, unflip) the co-ordinate system.

Comment: Yes, this code is what I use for flipping Quartz drawing in some of my applications, so it should work.

Comment: Again:  I'm using that exact code. It results in an empty view. I'm not sure what's going wrong, but without those two lines, it draws correctly, just upside-down.

Comment: The code as Peter corrected it (thanks, BTW, I forgot to swap the lines!) definitely works here. Can you post the entire code of your `drawRect:` method?

Comment: The code as posted should draw the PDF source file, right-side-up, with a white gradient background. Is that what is happening?

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing differently here. Is there anything special that you've configured in IB, or in the view class, or anything?

I don't know if it is related, but this is inside a library which is getting loaded into another app:  but that shouldn't change anything.

Comment: This might have something to do with it. Here is the PDF I am using, try using it:  http://zcr.me/f/A.pdf

Comment: Interesting, your PDF fails as you describe.

Comment: Does anyone know what might be causing that? The PDF seems fairly standard as glyphs go. I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: Carter Allen: You're not releasing your CGGradient or CGColorSpace objects. `rect` is the rect you need to draw; it isn't necessarily the whole bounds of the view, so you might be drawing the page into too small of a rectangle for you to see it. Don't forget to take the page's art box origin into account. (Also, are you sure you don't want the media box or crop box?) Have you verified that `pdfPage` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Overall, the PDFs that I was using were formatted incorrectly for iOS and were causing lots of problems. Still, the system for creating resolution-independent images in the platform is shoddy at best, and could definitely use a little love considering the variety of screen sizes available right now. With a properly-formatted PDF, the code works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, currentPage);
CGContextSaveGState(context);




CGRect box = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);

CGContextScaleCTM(context, self.bounds.size.width/box.size.width, self.bounds.size.height/box.size.height);
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

This is the right answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

To scale before translate, I think we can put minus when translate.

```
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -rect.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

This flips everything right side up for me:

```
pdfDisplayView.layer.geometryFlipped = YES; //(NO)
```